# Take the last N elements of an array instead of first elements in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Quick question.  I have the following:

```
$domain = "my.new.domain.com"
$domain.Split('.')[0,1]
```

...which returns the value:

```
my
new
```

That's great except I need the LAST TWO (domain.com) and am unsure how to do that.  Unfortunately the number of splits is variable (e.g. test.my.new.domain.com).  How does one say "go to the end and count X splits backwards"?

Comment: `[0,1]` -> `[-2,-1]`

Comment: Thank you - worked perfectly.  Didn't even dawn on me to try negative positions.

Comment: `[-N,-1]` in fact returns the N-th and 1st from last. If you like that syntax, you need to use `[-N..-1]` instead. You can also consider using `|select -Last N` which I described below in the answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To take last `N` elements of an array, you can use either of the following options:

- `$array | select -Last n`
- `$array[-n..-1]` (← '..' is the [Range Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#range-operator-))

**Example**

```
$domain = "my.new.domain.com"
$domain.Split('.') | select -Last 2
```

Will result in:

```
domain
com
```

**Note**

Using the [`select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) cmdlet, you can do some jobs that you usually do using [LINQ in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), for example:

- Take first N elements: `$array | select -First N`
- Take last N elements: `$array | select -Last N`
- Skip first N elements: `$array | select -Skip N`
- Skip last N elements: `$array | select -SkipLast N`
- Skip and take from first: `$array | select -Skip N -First M`
- Skip and take from last: `$array | select -Skip N -Last M`
- Select distinct elements: `$array | select -Distinct`
- select elements at index: `$array | select -Index (0,2,4)`